# Does having more tables in a bq dataset slow processes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My dataset had around 30000 tables. I have archived them all into 300 partitioned tables now. I Have deleted 29700 tables. The data volume is same as deleted tables were all archived first. Will it affect processing time of python scripts that use this dataset for creating new tables daily?

PS: I am not concerned about processes that use the archived tables. I am concerned about the processes that only uses the same dataset to create their new tables.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery doesn't mind if you have 3 tables or 30,000 tables. That shouldn't affect querying speed.

But! Imagine if a UI tries to list all tables in one dataset, or similar operations in other environments. That will be slower for sure.